# How can I get the filename from this ActionDispatch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I upload a file and request the following params:

```
params[:product][:images_attributes]["0"][:image]
```

it returns:

```
#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fcbe5c8f768 @original_filename="motorized-bicycle-9.jpeg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"product[images_attributes][0][image]\"; filename=\"motorized-bicycle-9.jpeg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n", @tempfile=#<File:/var/folders/qf/gjxv0pl142scx9131j0k65_00000gs/T/RackMultipart20140328-969-12np4s4>>
```

What is the ruby code that I would use to get the `filename`?

Comment: try this `params[:product][:images_attributes]["0"][:image].original_filename`

Comment: @product.description.file.filename will give humanized file name

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

```
params[:product][:images_attributes]["0"][:image].original_filename
```

`#original_filename` should be the name of the file that the user uploaded, from the [documentation on ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Http/UploadedFile.html).