# Get a file name from ActionDispatch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this path coming in my terminal but I am unable to fetch the filename .

```
{"profile"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x0000000371fe28 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20160524-10164-1tytgpj.png>, @original_filename="abcas.png", @content_type="image/png", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"user[profile]\"; filename=\"abcas.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n">}
```

I am trying

```
**puts "dddd#{ params[:user][:profile].original_filename}"**
```

but getting this error **undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass**
I have look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22720556/how-can-i-get-the-filename-from-this-actiondispatch) but wasn't helpful

Comment: Judging by your params, it looks like `params[:user]` is nil. Try `params[:profile].original_filename` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a space between `params` and `[:user][:profile].original_filename`

So try : `params[:user][:profile].original_filename`

Comment: I have updated my question please see.And Bymistake I have given space

Comment: @AniketShivamTiwari Could you run the query (the one that gets you an error) and do `raise params.inspect` and put the result in your question please ?